# Rails server says port already used, how to kill that process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm on a mac, doing:

```
rails server
```

I get:

```
2010-12-17 12:35:15] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2010-12-17 12:35:15] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16) [i686-darwin10.4.0]
[2010-12-17 12:35:15] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
Exiting
```

I know I can start one on a new port, but I want to kill this process.

Answer (score 783, accepted):

Assuming you're looking to kill whatever is on port 3000 (which is what webrick normally uses), type this in your terminal to find out the PID of the process:

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

Then, use the number in the PID column to kill the process:

```
$ kill -9 PID
```

Comment: could you please explain *-wni*

Comment: Just to clarify for novices: in the second line of code, you are supposed to replace the `PID` with the actual number that is shown in your console upon entering the first line of code (eg, `12345`).

Comment: You can also find the PID by navigating through your rails directory to the following file tmp/pids/server.pid

Comment: This can happen if you're running debugger in RubyMine and it crashes or something... The server stops but the debugger continues... Anyway, this is the solution I used and it works perfectly :)

Comment: @tandy this is a good way of getting the PID for a specific project however, sometimes when a process suddenly closes, the file might be absent but the server could still be running. Doing a `lsof -wni tcp:3000` will *always* show *all* processes listening on that protocol:port combination. (where 3000 is to be replaced with your local server port. e.g. in Rails this is 3000 by default).

Comment: Please don't use `kill -9` (`SIGKILL`) habitually.  Use it when needed, but otherwise the default signal (`SIGTERM`) should be fine, and allows a process to clean up if/what it needs to.  (`SIGKILL` forces it to die immediately, with no chance to, for example, finish writing a file, or the like.)  I see no information in this question that indicates that the process isn't responding to `SIGTERM`.

Comment: On MacOS you can also do this in Activity Monitor by looking for the 'ruby' process name and clicking the x icon

Answer (score 170):

`kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)`

Comment: everything between the parentheses will return a process id that using the  port 3000. And `-t` means `specifies  that  lsof should produce terse output with process identifiers only and no header - e.g., so that the output  may be piped to kill(1).` than I guess you know what `kill` will do

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is an 'all in one' line. Put this in an alias and you're good to go.

Comment: If an explanation were included, this would definitely be worth an upvote.

Comment: This will kill all processes including all opened browser session. So you want to be careful when you try it out.

Comment: Please see my comment on the accepted answer about using `kill -9` by rote/habitually.

Comment: Thanks @lindes. The only time I use kill -9 on rails server is when my puma server freezes and I'm forced to `kill -9`.

Comment: All other answers should be deleted and only have this one. I use it HABITUALLY ;D

Answer (score 43):

You need to get process id of program using tcp port 3000. To get process id

```
lsof -i tcp:3000 -t
```

And then using that process id, simply kill process using ubuntu kill command.

```
kill -9 pid
```

Or just run below mentioned combine command. It will first fetch pid and then kill that process.

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)
```

Comment: Please see my comment on the accepted answer about using `kill -9` by rote/habitually.

Answer (score 18):

For anyone stumbling across this question that is not on a Mac: assuming you know that your server is running on port 3000, you can do this in one shot by executing the following:

```
fuser -k 3000/tcp
```

But as Toby has mentioned, the implementation of fuser in Mac OS is rather primitive and this command will not work on mac.

Comment: This will not work on the mac (Mac was stipulated in the question) as fuser only accepts c, f, and u as options.

Comment: I have updated the answer and it addresses how to use it for mac users as well. There is no reason to down vote especially considering others , including myself stumbled upon this question in the past despite not being on a mac.

Comment: Adding a `-v` flag also shows a small amount of info about what process got killed.  So `fuser -kv 3000/tcp`.  Alas that MacOS's fuser doesn't have this ability. `kill $(lsof -ti tcp:3000)` is a fairly close equivalent, though.

Answer (score 17):

Some times there is a chance where rails server not closed properly.
You can find process used by rails

> ps aux | grep rails

Output will be like

```
user     12609  9.8  0.5  66456 45480 pts/0    Sl+  21:06   0:02 /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/ruby bin/rails s
```

Here process_id 12609 is used by your rails server.

You can kill it easily by command

> kill -9 12609

Comment: This has become "ps aux | grep ruby" for me. Maybe from the switch from webrick to puma

Comment: Please see my comment on the accepted answer about using `kill -9` by rote/habitually.

Comment: I had to do this to find the right process `ps aux | grep puma`

Answer (score 13):

All the answers above are really good but I needed a way to type as little as possible in the terminal so I created a gem for that. You can install the gem only once and run the command 'shutup' every time you wanna kill the Rails process (while being in the current folder).

`gem install shutup`

then go in the current folder of your rails project and run

`shutup` # this will kill the Rails process currently running

You can use the command 'shutup' every time you want

DICLAIMER: I am the creator of this gem

NOTE: if you are using rvm install the gem globally

```
rvm @global do gem install shutup
```

Comment: this is neat. Looking at the source, your gem looks for the pid file, but that's not guaranteed to exist. the `lsof` approach is more dependable.

Comment: @maxpleaner: true, and also more likely to kill some other process that may be listening on that port, in case that was done (perhaps by accident).

Comment: It works here. If you are reading this in 2019, please install this gem, it really works, so much easier.. just run gem install shutup in  your folder, and everytime you need to kill just type "shutup"

Comment: I installedl this gem, and ran it and it killed Sinatra. However, from now the default port 4567 doesn't respond, nor any other port set by the 'set :port XXXX' command. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 6):

The existing answers are great, but I found that Bijan's answer cast too wide a net, catching up processes that could be unrelated.

Here's a 1-liner that combines port as well as `ruby` as a string search

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t -c ruby -a)
```

Breaking down how it works:

`kill -9` will kill processes that are listed. But first run the command within `$( )`

`lsof -i tcp:3000` lists all processes on that port

`-t` is terse mode, so just the pid

`-c` searches by command, which in this case is `ruby` since i'm using puma

`-a` is for `all`, and combines the `-i` and `-c` together

Answer (score 5):

By default, rails server uses port 3000.
So, you have 2 options to run rails server.
1. Either you can run the server on other port by defining custom port using the following command
`rails s -p 3001`
2. Or you can kill all the running ruby process by running following command
`killall -9 ruby`
then run `rails server`

Comment: ´killall -9 ruby´ worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Using this command you can kill the server:

```
ps aux|grep rails
```

Answer (score 3):

One line solution:

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'rails s' | awk {'print$2'}); rails s
```

Answer (score 1):

Type in terminal:

```
lsof -i :3000
```

replace PID:

```
kill -9 [PID]
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is a script for WSL that kills processes in windows

```
PIDS=$(/mnt/c/windows/system32/cmd.exe /c netstat -ano | /mnt/c/windows/system32/cmd.exe /c findstr :$1 | awk '{print $5}')
for pid in $PIDS
do
    /mnt/c/windows/system32/cmd.exe /c wmic process where "processid=$pid" delete
done
```

example

```
myscriptname 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pid` is stored in `tmp/pids/server.pid` while a rails app is running. Just run `kill -9 PID_NUMBER_HERE` to kill it.

Alternatively, add this code to your app at `bin/kill_server`:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

# Kills the active server process

# Check if the server is running
if [ ! -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  echo "Server is not running"
  exit 1
fi

# Set active server pid to variable
pid=$(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)

# Kill the server
kill -9 $pid

# Remove the pid file
rm tmp/pids/server.pid

# Echo success
echo "Server killed (pid $pid)"
```

Whenever you need to kill the server in the future, just run `bin/kill_server`. If your terminal returns a permission denied error, run `chmod +x bin/kill_server` to make it executable.

Answer (score -4):

Type in:

```
man lsof
```

Then look for -w, -n, and -i

-i: internet stuff
-n: makes it faster
-w: toggles warnings

There are WAY more details on the man pages

Answer (score -6):

If you are on windows machine follow these steps.

```
c:/project/
cd tmp
c:/project/tmp
cd pids
c:/project/tmp/pids
dir
```

There you will a file called server.pid

delete it.

```
c:/project/tmp/pid> del *.pid
```

Thats it.

**EDIT:** [Please refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088163/cant-stop-rails-server)

Comment: This will not stop the server.

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question (in particular, why you think a suggestion for a Windows machine might be useful for a question that states that it's on MacOS) would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.