# Unable to start webbrick - TCPServer Error: Address already in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am receiving the following error:

```
$rails server --binding=127.0.0.1
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://127.0.0.1:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-04-04 13:02:35] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-04-04 13:02:35] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
[2012-04-04 13:02:35] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
Exiting
/Users/TravisKs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `new'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `block in create_listeners'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:70:in `each'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:70:in `create_listeners'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:74:in `listen'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:62:in `initialize'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:24:in `initialize'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rvm-gemset-name/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in `new' 
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rvm-gemset-name/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in `run' 
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rvm-gemset-name/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rvm-gemset-name/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rvm-gemset-name/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rvm-gemset-name/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap' 
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rvm-gemset-name/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

After restarting my machine I still have this problem. I have reviewed other SO posts on the TCPServer error with Rails.

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,user,args,stat
```

Returns no results for rails

```
ps aux
```

Does not return any Zombie Processes (Z in the stat column) or Rails servers.

This is odd to me since everything was working fine. I switched a gemset, reinstalled Rails 3.1.1, and now I am unable to run it.

Comment: Does it start up if you explicitly set a port `rails server -p 3001`?

Comment: It does, I plan on some work around but would love to resolve this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261477/tcpserver-error-address-already-in-use-bind2

Comment: Rails server says port already used, how to kill that process? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473229/rails-server-says-port-already-used-how-to-kill-that-process

Answer (score 8):

try running `lsof | grep 3000` and then `kill -9 <number of process>`
if it doesn't help, try running the rails server with `-p 3001` option to change the port

Comment: I get this but assume it's becuase of the 6300000 and not what we're looking for. \ Google     374 travisKs  txt      REG       14,2    630000 39109688

Comment: I had the same issue because I had an Aptana debug session running, which didn't show up with `lsof`. But the server started fine once I terminated the debug session.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i know it's to late to answer, but this very same day i had same problem.

All i did is, Restart my machine. seems like other application was using the same port !..

so, by simply restarting, problem solved!