# TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Jekyll was working fine for me few weeks back but now all of a sudden it gives me the following error:

```
TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7300 port=4000

 % lsof -i :4000
 <fetches nothing>
```

Even though nothing is running on the port. Below are the details:

```
 % jekyll --version
Jekyll 0.11.2
 % where jekyll
/home/bhaarat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/jekyll
/usr/bin/jekyll
 % ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
 % rvm --version
rvm 1.10.0
```

Here is the output

```
 % jekyll --server
Configuration from /home/bhaarat/blog/omnipresent.github.com/_config.yml
Auto-regenerating enabled: /home/bhaarat/blog/omnipresent.github.com -> /home/bhaarat/blog/omnipresent.github.com/_site
[2012-04-21 13:46:40] regeneration: 38 files changed
[2012-04-21 13:46:40] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-04-21 13:46:40] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [i686-linux]
[2012-04-21 13:46:40] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
[2012-04-21 13:46:40] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7382 port=4000
```

I know the address isn't in use and jekyll is probably breaking for some other reason but throwing that error. What are my options? I've tried re-installing as well.

Comment: How exactly do you know the address isn't in use?

Comment: i'm trying `lsof -i :<port number>` plus same thing is happening on a different box

Comment: What happens if you specify an alternate port?

Comment: unfortunately, the same thing. Whats the best way to completely remove jekyll and reinstall it.

Comment: If you used Ruby gem to install, you should be able to uninstall with `gem uninstall jekyll`. If you didn't maybe install with gem to overwrite the existing version. Did you try hitting the port with your browser or telnet to see if that provides any help?

Comment: Have you tried going to `localhost:4000` while Jekyll is running? I get the same warning but the server still works.

Comment: Have you tried with sudo to see what is running on the port? I mean sudo fuser -n tcp 8080

Comment: The thing is, nothing listens on :4000. Something is broken in Jekyll.

Comment: Did you try `jekyll --no-server --no-auto`? I get `found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 2 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)`. `jekyll --server` is similar to yours.

Comment: Friggin Ruby based BS always has the dumbest bugs. How on earth can someone get wrong whether a port is in use? Why the hell does Bootstrap 3 use this buggy crap.

Comment: I had to `sudo` the `lsof` command. Without `sudo`, `lsof` returned nothing.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Type this in your terminal to find out the PID of the process that's using the 3000 port:

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

Then, use the number in the PID column to kill the process:

```
$ kill -9 PID
```

Comment: To anyone reading this, make sure that in the last command, you substitute `PID` with the actual number that you see under the PID. for example, I ran `kill -9 11734`

Comment: Note that the problem can also be a harmless warning coming from an IPv6 configuration issue: the server first binds to a dual-stack IPv4+IPv6 address, then it also tries to bind to a IPv6-only address; and the latter doesn't work because the IPv6 address is already taken by the previous dual-stack socket.

Comment: try this instead `lsof -wni tcp:3000 | xargs -I{} kill -9 {}` of running both command

Answer (score 18):

I was not qualified to post comment. So I added a new answer.

I encountered this problem on Mac OS X 10.10.3. And I had never installed/used Jekyll before. I was not able to start jekyll server with its default port number 4000. The reason was that the port was the same as what NoMachine used. With

```
$ sudo lsof -wni tcp:4000
```

Note: Running this command without `sudo` will have no output.

I saw this output:

```
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nxd     449   nx    3u  IPv4 0x8d22************      0t0  TCP *:terabase (LISTEN)
nxd     449   nx    4u  IPv6 0x8d22************      0t0  TCP *:terabase (LISTEN)
```

The port 4000 was occupied by `nxd`, which was the process started by NoMachine. And

```
$ sudo kill -9 449
```

would not work, because NoMachine's nxd process would keep restarting, with a new PID.

Therefore, I had to either:

- Changed my jekyll server port in the site `_config.yml` to another spared one. I appended the line below to `_config.yml` and it worked.

  `port: 3000 # change server port to 3000`

or

- Changed NoMachine's default nxd port, or Uninstall NoMachine

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't figure out what terabase was until I stumbled upon this answer.

Answer (score 11):

`Ctrl-Z` doesn't terminate a program, but rather suspends it and sends it to the background. You can resume the program with the "fg" command. To actually terminate it, use `Ctrl-C`.

The actual error message seems to be bogus and can be ignored. I am getting the same error message "address in use" but jekyll works fine anyway at the expected port.

Comment: I am also getting the error message but I can run my site off :4000

Answer (score 3):

I have met this problem recently.

I tried out all the method mentioned above, and even restarted my computer, but still couldn't solve it!!! Then I removed the jekyll and installed a new version, it just worked.

`gem uninstall jekyll & gem install jekyll` (maybe you need super user priviledge).

If you really get annoyed with similar bugs, this sb method is worth a try...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the top answer, I came up with a simple way

`lsof -wni tcp:3000 | xargs -I{} kill -9 {}`

It takes the output of finding PID in which port the tcp server is running at. In this case it is `3000`.

It then kills the processes running that
PID

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have another terminal open where you are already running a server.
If that is the case, do a *CTRL-C* to shutdown the server, and that will free the port/address.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find PID of the process that's using the 3000 port:

```
 $ps -ef
```

Output Like this:

```
1003      4953  2614  0 08:51 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
1003      5634     1  0 08:56 pts/0    00:00:00 spring server | moviestore | started 2 hours ago                                           
1003      5637  5634  0 08:56 ?        00:00:01 spring app    | moviestore | started 2 hours ago | development mode                                                              
1003      6078  4953  0 09:03 pts/0    00:00:03 puma 3.6.0 (tcp://localhost:3000) [moviestore]              
1003      6117  2614  0 09:03 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
root      6520     2  0 09:57 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:2]
root      6936  1225  0 11:09 ?        00:00:00 [lightdm] <defunct>
1003      7084     1  0 11:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/apport/apport-gtk
1003      7475     1  0 11:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/apport/apport-gtk
root      8739  1225  1 11:29 tty8     00:00:11 /usr/bin/X :1 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp vt8 -novtswitch
root      8853  1225  0 11:29 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 13 22
1002      8943     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
1002      8954  8853  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 gnome-session --session=ubuntu
1002      8992  8954  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
1002      8995     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
1002      8996     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
1002      9007  8954  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
1002      9015     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
1002      9018  8954  1 11:30 ?        00:00:07 compiz
1002      9021     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
1002      9028  8954  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
1002      9029  8954  0 11:30 ?        00:00:01 nautilus -n
1002      9030  8954  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-fallback-mount-helper
1002      9031  8954  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 nm-applet
1002      9032  8954  0 11:30 ?        00:00:02 /opt/mTrac/mTrac
1002      9033  8954  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 bluetooth-applet
1002      9045  9032  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/mTrac/mTrac --type=zygote --no-sandbox
1002      9050     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
1002      9054     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
1002      9057     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
1002      9062     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
```

here you can see :

```
1003      6078  4953  0 09:03 pts/0    00:00:03 puma 3.6.0 (tcp://localhost:3000) [moviestore]
```

localhost:3000 have `pid: 6078`

kill that process  by

```
$sudo kill 6078
```

then run

```
$rails s
```

Answer (score 0):

we can user fuser command

`fuser -k 3000/tcp`

Answer (score -1):

**work around**

in `/_site` run: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`