# When starting WEBrick/Jekyll it produces a TCPServer Error (Address already in use)

Tags: ruby, jekyll, webrick

I'm trying to start my local Jekyll server but it just won't work and no matter which port I choose it always comes down to the error:

> WARN TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind (2)

I tried to follow some instructions online, which mostly assumed a specific port was already in use, but this doesn't seem to be the case here, since absolutely no port works and commands such as "lsof | grep 4000", etc.  produces nothing.

Jekyll version: 0.11.2
Ruby: 1.9.2.-p290

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
netstat -a -n -p | grep LIST
```

and search for you port number ( 4000 )
then kill it  - the pid should be the last column

If there is no pid at the end then execute the command as root or make a sudo.

Comment: doesn't show anything on 4000 unfortunately. not even on sudo

Comment: It's on Ubuntu 12.04. It did work a few months ago, but after updating everything on the machine I wanted to resume work and just can't get it to work :(

Comment: in a similar [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261477/tcpserver-error-address-already-in-use-bind2?rq=1) they suggest trying this one `jekyll --no-server --no-auto` as the server is not starting for some other error but complaining about the address like in your case.

Comment: yeah but this only compiles the files. (same as just `jekyll`)

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention the compiling works. `jekyll --auto` btw works too. It's just the WEBrick Server that is bugged :/

Comment: Try changing the port to 4001 for example.

Comment: to quote my first question: "no matter which port I choose " I tried a few other ports with no success