# Path to gem (e.g. /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/) when Ruby is installed using RVM?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, ubuntu-12.04, jekyll

First-time Ruby user here, and Jekyll is the reason.

First, I installed RVM (on Ubuntu Server 12.04 64-bit):

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

And followed the subsequent instructions as guided by the installation process (for e.g. adding `source ~/.profile` to `~/.bash_profile`). **The [FULL INSTRUCTIONS I followed are here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eacf424d0435e9834010).**

Read output of `rvm requirements` command, and installed all the necessary binaries.

Installed Ruby 1.9.3, configured RVM to use it, and then installed RubyGems, by issuing the following command one after the other:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3
rvm rubygems current
```

Ran `ruby --version` to be sure I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.

Then installed Jekyll using the gem:

```
gem install jekyll
```

Setup the basic site structure by copying the contents of [**jekyll/site** provided by the official Jekyll repository](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/tree/master/site), then made the necessary changes to `_config.yml` and `CNAME`.

**Here's the thing!** When I run `jekyll --server` I get the same old [TCP/Webrick error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10261477/1071413) (but none of the solutions work).

So, [as the Jekyll wiki says](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Usage#running-jekyll), it's probably this:

> On Debian or Ubuntu, you may need to add `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/` to your path.

The problem is:

1. In my case, `/var/lib/gems/...` doesn't exist. Probably because I installed Ruby, RubyGems, all using RVM. So, what'd be the path in my case?
2. Again, if I know the path, how am I supposed to *"to add `/var/lib/gems/*.*/bin/` to your path"*?

Comment: could be in ~/.rvm/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can just ignore this problem, if you mean

```
[2012-04-21 13:46:40] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
```

It's because some buggy code in latest version of jekyll on RubyGems, however, it seems to have been corrected in the [latest code on github](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll). The server created by jekyll tries to bind on both IPv4('0.0.0.0') and IPv6('::'), so the first bind succeeds and the bind on IPv6 fails and an warning is logged.

Take a look at the jekyll executable in your `~/.rvm` directory, maybe `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/jekyll`, at about line 288:

```rb
s = HTTPServer.new(
  :Port            => options['server_port'],
  :MimeTypes       => mime_types
)
```

Here `HTTPServer` is `WEBrick::HTTPServer`. jekyll creates the server without specifying `:BindAddress` configuration. And the bind address is set to `nil` as default.

WEBrick will call `Socket.getaddrinfo` to get the real addresses from the bind address specified, which, when passed in a `nil` address, returns wildcard address for both IPv4('0.0.0.0') and IPv6('::'). Later, WEBrick calls `TCPServer.new(address, port)` to create TCPServer. And this is where the `TCPServer Error` arises.

For more details, read [`WEBrick::Utils.create_listeners`](https://github.com/nahi/webrick/blob/master/lib/webrick/utils.rb#L71)

Comment: You may be right, but I just figured that adding `server: false` in my _config.yml fixed it. Any idea why? It works now, but I really want to know why.

Comment: @TheoneManis it doesn't make sense. Command line options has higher precedence than the configuration file `_config.yml`. If you specify `--server` command line option, the configuration entry `server: false` will have no effect.

Comment: Okay. Then I create an issue on Jekyll github repo and see if I can get some info (and report back here).

Comment: @TheoneManis It seems that they have fixed the issue in the latest source code. Although RubyGems still uses buggy version.