# Rails 4, rails server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

When I run `rails server`, I have the following error:

```
rails server                                                                                                       
=> Booting WEBrick                                                                                                 
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on localhost:3000                                          
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options                                                                  
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server                                                                                       
[2013-12-26 23:29:07] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1                                                                          
[2013-12-26 23:29:07] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]                                                 
[2013-12-26 23:29:07] WARN  TCPServer Error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/po    
rt) is normally permitted. - bind(2)                                                                               
Exiting                                                                                                            
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `initialize': Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/    
network address/port) is normally permitted. - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)                                         
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `new'                                                
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `block in create_listeners'                          
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `each'                                               
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `create_listeners'                                   
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:132:in `listen'                                           
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:113:in `initialize'                                       
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in `initialize'                                    
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:11:in `new'                
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:11:in `run'                
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'                      
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'         
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (req    
uired)>'                                                                                                           
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'                  
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'     
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'                                                                              
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention you are running Windows and using vagrant, I'll make the assumption that vagrant is running a POSIX based operating system such as Debian, CentOS, etc.

You should `ssh` into the vagrant machine and find the process of the `WEBrick` server that is running and terminate it. You may need to do `sudo` if the instance was started by a process or job having a different UID than your user.

To find a process id to kill you can use `ps`. However since you know the port that is being used, you could use `fuser` with the -k flag as well.

```
fuser -k 3000/tcp
```

or

```
sudo fuser -k 3000/tcp
```

or any of the following:

[Rails server says port already used, how to kill that process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473229/rails-server-says-port-already-used-how-to-kill-that-process/14859801#14859801)

If you require `sudo` and you are not in the `sudoers` file and cannot `su` to root (don't know the password) or access the user or group that started the process, contact whomever set you up with the vagrant instance and ask how you can have your credentials added to `sudoers`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a problem using the default port, try another port.

For example:

```
rails server -p 4000
```

Comment: hi, i followed exactly what was explained in the rails4 todo lists tutorial here at treehouse on how to install rpec, but i didnt have the directories helpers,views, controller, and the rest, pls how can i generate theses directories,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have no other Rails servers running.

Answer (score 0):

There is another process running on the same port.

If that's a webrick, Try `killall -9 ruby` and check again.

Comment: am on a windows machine using vagrant, its says killall is nor a valid command

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that. Kill the process with process manager then.

Comment: well am using virtual box and i dont see any ruby or rails stuff running, i dont know if am looking at the right thing or not.thanks

Answer (score 0):

To Ensure that no rails server is running now, you need to do something like this:

Go App root directory -> tmp -> pids and then delete server.pid

It will ensure that no process is runing for your server and then restart your server once again.

1. Or you can run your rails server by using another port if u need then run the bellow command in the terminal or command prompt:

   ```
                          rails server -p 5000
   ```
2. Or you may try this :

   ```
                         lsof -wni tcp:3000
   ```

And then kill the process, collect PID from the result of above command:

```
                           kill -9 PID
```

Comment: hi, i followed exactly what was explained in the rails4 todo lists tutorial here at treehouse on how to install rpec, but i didnt have the directories helpers,views, controller, and the rest, pls how can i generate theses directories,thanks