# WEBrick Server not running with rails 5.0.0.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and am trying to set up a basic, local web server in order to dive into all the framework has to offer. I've installed rails using
    gem install rails
and have everything seeming to work. However, I also downloaded rails 5.0.0.rc1. When I call to boot up the server with
    rails s
or
    bin/rails server
it just ends up with a blank screen on http://localhost:3000. Does this have anything to do with the installation of rails 5.0.0.rc1? Why am I just getting a blank screen and not the default information page which signals that it is working?

Comment: please run `ps aux | grep 'ruby'`, maybe other rails server is working. This answer might be usefull also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4473322/6266499

Comment: The information on the linked worked perfectly