# Address already in use - bind(2) when starting server in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide, webrick

When starting the server in Cloud9, `rails s -p $PORT -b $IP`, I get an error and the server fails to start.

```
Address already in use - bind(2)
```

Following this post, [Rails server says port already used, how to kill that process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473229/rails-server-says-port-already-used-how-to-kill-that-process),

I ran `lsof -wni tcp:8080` (8080 because of cloud9)

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby 18415 ubuntu    9u  IPv4 698526934      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

Then,

```
kill -18415 PID
```

But this results in an error,

```
bash: kill: 18415: invalid signal specification
```

Can anyone advise how to fix this error on Cloud9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're killing it with the wrong way.
You need to use:

```
kill -9 18415
```

9 - signal 'kill'
18415 - process id

Also you can kill all ruby processes like this:

```
killall -9 ruby
```

But use it only when you know what you're doing.